# Laptop battery full charge capacity drops

Tags: laptop, battery

Recently i've bought an ASUS VivoBook S15 S530FN-EJ085T and after less then a week i noticed (througt HWMonitor) that the li-ion battery's full charge capacity value is slightly lower then the design capacity value, is this some built-in configuration to prevent the full charge of the battery or there is some problem already? Right now my approach to the recharge "problem" is recharge whenever the battery drops around 25%~20% then attach the AC until the battery reaches the full charge. During the day i use laptop's battery and attach the AC to it only when needed. There are different opinions about the best practice to use in these cases but i'm a little bit confused because these ideas are really opposite to each other. Can you give some advice and tell me if there is something wrong with my laptop's battery?

[image: HWMonitor Diagnosis]

Took the screenshot after a battery full recharge. Each column of the screenshot shows: the current, minimum and maximum value of each parameter registered since the startup of the program. Literally 2 seconds ago the wear level was 2%, now is 4%! What the heck is going on?

Comment: What are the three columns showing? Battery handling advice may vary drastically depending on the chemistry, so if you could include that in your question that would be useful... e.g: Li-Ion / LiPo / etc...

Comment: Question edited. Each column of the screenshot shows: the current, minimum and maximum value of each parameter registered since the startup of the program. The laptop's battery is a Li-Ion battery.

Comment: So you are using the battery all day? You are discharging, charging, discharging all day? Of course, it will wear out with 2-5 Cycles each day quickly.

Comment: But actually, besides that, I guess the first 5% will wear very quickly. Then it should go much slower.

Comment: @davidbaumann Your statement makes perfectly sense, no doubt about it, but many articles online are discordant about this, some declare that you should use your battery after it reaches 80% of the charge.